# Format the file name parsed via errorformat in vim

Tags: android, vim, gradle, android-studio

I am trying to write an errorformat to detect errors when compiling android applications using the new gradle build system (http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system).

`errorformat=%f:%l:\ error:\ %m`

This errorformat catches the XML errors but in gradle the filename that comes in the output is not the original source filename, instead it is a temporary build file:

`/home/user/Studio/myapp/build/res/all/debug/layout/add_child_dialog.xml:7: error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix`

The original source file is:

`/home/user/Studio/myapp/res/layout/add_child_dialog.xml:7: error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix`

As you can see the error shows a file inside the build folder and it contains the build type  (*debug*) in it.

I read the quickfix-window help and found ways to modify the quickfix output using the *QuickfixCmdPost* and *quickfix* BufReadPost auto-commands but these take effect after the quickfix window is parsed by the errorformat. As result I can see the correct source file on the quickfix window but vim still jumps to the wrong file.

Is there a way to modify the file (%f) after it is parsed by errorformat?
Is there a way to tell gradle to print the original source file and not the build one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either transform the quickfix list on `QuickFixCmdPost` (using `getqflist()` and `setqflist()`, with the correct file in the `filename` attribute), or append a script to `'makeprg'` that transforms the output (e.g. using `sed`).

But I agree with you that the tool output is wrong and should be fixed (to state the original files, not temporary copies), instead of working around this in Vim.